# Why does Corona give an error loading code that loads fine with lua?

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I'm having problems with a specific line of code - `building.transmitter:[operation](player, unpack({...}))` that causes an error in Corona, yet this loads fine when it's run in Lua separately.  I suspect it has something to do with the `:` being placed before the `[operation]` variable but I'm clueless why.

Specifically the module is written as,

```
local activate = {}

local function activate.transmitter(player, operation, ...) 
  building = player:getTile()   
  building.transmitter:[operation](player, unpack({...}))
end

return activate
```

The runtime errror that is appearing gives me

```
"error loading module from file, '<name>' expected near '['"
```

Edit - WOW!  I didn't notice that when troubleshooting this in Corona I changed some of the lines of code to identify the problem.  I then mistakenly tested the *edited* code in Lua and it ran fine.  I didn't realize the code wasn't the original until siffiejoe pointed out the interpreter getting an error as well.  Sorry for the mistake.

Comment: Every Lua interpreter I tried (5.1.5, 5.2.3, 5.3-beta, luajit 2.1-alpha) agrees with Corona on this one ...

Comment: I didn't notice this until you pointed it out.  I even had a [screenshot](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/42307676/junk/Screenshot%202014-11-03%2018.52.56.png) ready to display to you before I rechecked the code, and I noticed a few pieces were different.

Answer (score 1):

maybe Corona uses older version of Lua which does not support this syntax. You can try workaround instead of

```
building.transmitter:[operation](player, unpack({...}));
```

you can call

```
building.transmitter[operation](building.transmitter, player, unpack({...}));
```

Comment: No official version of Lua supports this `:[` syntax.